# Is there a Ruby way to remove boilerplate code in initializers?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

I write lots of `initialize` code that sets attrs to parameters, similar to this:

```
  class SiteClient
    attr_reader :login, :password, :domain

    def initialize(login, password, domain='somedefaultsite.com')
      @login = login
      @password = password
      @domain = domain
    end
  end
```

Is there a more Ruby way of doing this? I feel like I'm writing that same boilerplate setup code over and over.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Ruby [`Struct`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Struct.html):

```
class MyClass < Struct.new(:login, :password, :domain)
end
```

Or you can try some gems for that, i.e. [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus):

```
class MyClass
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :login, String
  attribute :password, String
  attribute :domain, String
end
```

And then (in both cases):

```
MyClass.new(login: 'a', password: 'b', domain: 'c')
```

Comment: Struct is a great option here. It's concise, conveys your intent, and it's built-in.

Comment: Using a `Struct` will make all fields read-write (as opposed to read-only as in the code shown by the OP).

Comment: You can use `protected :login=, :password=, :domain=` when need to restrict access.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a bit better like this:

```
def initialize(login, password, site = 'somedefaultsite.com')
  @login, @password, @domain = login, password, domain
end
```

and if you don't have an optional argument, then you can be a bit more lazy:

```
def initialize(*a)
  @login, @password, @domain = a
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a gem called [`fattr`](https://github.com/ahoward/fattr) that you can include in your Ruby application or gem to do exactly this.

```
require 'fattr'
class SiteClient
  fattr :login
  fattr :password
  fattr :domain => 'somedefaultsite.com'

  def initialize(**attributes)
    attributes.each do |k, v|
      public_send k, v
    end
  end
end

client = SiteClient.new
client.username = 'susan'
client.password = 'anything'

another_client = SiteClient.new username: 'bob', password: 'p@ssword1'
```

In this example the `fattr` method will define the reader and writer methods for each attribute defined. Also, it can assign each attribute a default value. The initializer is set to accept a hash of key value pairs which it will iterate through to populate the attributes by calling the attribute method with the value to be assigned.

Something to be aware of is this example will generate both the reader and writer methods for your attributes. In your question, you are only using `attr_reader` so this may not be exactly what you need if you want your class data to be immutable. There might be a way to configure `fattr` to do this, but I haven't played with it that extensively yet.

Special thanks to Avdi Grimm and episode 276 of [RubyTapas](http://rubytapas.com/) which is where I learned about this.

Answer (score 0):

In [this DAS screencast](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/shorter-class-syntax), Gary Bernhardt walks through a few metaprogramming tricks that can shorten the syntax of common class constructs, one of which is the sort of initialize method you're describing. He bundled it into a [gem](https://github.com/garybernhardt/cls) as well, which would make your code look something like

```
class SiteClient
  extend Cls
  takes       :login, :password, :domain
  attr_reader :login, :password, :domain
end
```

If you're comfortable with a bit of monkey patching, you can also implement the `takes` method the way it's done in the screencast

```
class Module
  def takes(*names)
    define_method(:initialize) do |*values|
      names.zip(values).each do |name, value|
        instance_variable_set(:"@#{name}", value)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which removes the need for the `extend Cls` line from the example above.